# How to make a repetition div#header2 the entire length div#header1

Tags: html, css

Code:

```
#header1{width:100%;}

#header2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 72px;
    background: url("./image.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: -10px -180px;
}

<div id="header1">

<div id="header2">
</div>

</div>
```

Tell me please how to make a repetition div#header2 the entire length div#header1 ?

P.S.: `image.png` - it packs icons. (is a sprite image), ex. image pack down:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Could you please elaborate? What do you mean by "make a repetition div#header2 the entire length"? What is your expected result?

Comment: @SurjithSM i want get div with width 100% and background with one of blue band. in result i want get http://clip2net.com/clip/m264191/1387347838-clip-29kb.jpg

Comment: You should adjust your sprite image for this.

Comment: @SurjithSM i know how make with one image but i have other quetion. see question before ask and said.

Comment: I didn't told you to use one image. But adjust the sprite like remove the blue bar in the left and make the other one full width.

Comment: @SurjithSM i change image, see again now please

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle Example !](http://jsfiddle.net/y9sa5/1/)
Set `width:100%` in header2 .

```
#header1{width:100%;}

#header2{
width:100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;    
height: 72px;
background: url("./image.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
       }

<div id="header1">

<div id="header2">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @learner , Why My answer is not correct ? can you show me your icon ?

Comment: becouse you use one, but image.png - it image pack, i accept exmple image pack in question now, see please

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that can not be achieved with background-repeat.

The only solution that I know, and a little boring, is with multiple backgrounds, setting the same image enough times to cover the full length:

For 3 images, that would be:

```
.test1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}

.test2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300"),                    url("http://placekitten.com/200/300"), url("http://placekitten.com/200/300"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 200px 300px;
    background-position-x: -100px, 0px, 100px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DFr2L/)

I didn't had a sprites image at hand, but notice that the kitten face is a small part of the real image.

If you want to fill a real large div with a small image, you will need to write a quite long background image list. But I can not think of any other alternative .

Comment: not aright - you use one, but image.png - it image pack, i accept exmple image pack in question now, see please.

Comment: My answer is ok. I didn't use an image pack, but see that the cat image is cut. The same would apply to a image pack.